# Store os.urandom variable to Sqlite database in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

I'm trying to store random variable to Sqlite database in Django, but I get this error:

> You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Here is my code:

```
random_number = os.urandom(16)
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(number=random_number)
```

Models.py:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    random = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I use Python 2.7.10 and Django 1.9.

Comment: What's `SomeModel` like? What is the type of `SomeModel.number`? `os.urandom()` doesn't return numbers, it returns bytes (also str in python2).

Comment: I have made number field in model as a CharField, so maybe there is the problem. Yep, I know that it returns bytes, but how I can encode it, so Sqlite can store it? I'll update the model to the question.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield "A field to store raw binary data. It only supports bytes assignment. Be aware that this field has limited functionality. For example, it is not possible to filter a queryset on a BinaryField value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If still possible, you could alter your model to use [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    random = models.BinaryField(max_length=32)
```

If on the other hand the model is already set in stone, consider some binary to text encoding, like base64:

```
from base64 import b64encode

random_number = os.urandom(16)
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(number=b64encode(random_number))
```

Comment: It's possible to change the field to BinaryField and now it's working. Thanks!